# stl-like binary search tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I need:

- binary search tree C library like std::map
- with lower_bound operation
- with iterators stable across deletions

In C++ terms i need the following:

```
typedef std::map<K,V> map;
typedef map::iterator iter;
map m;
...
for (iter it = m.lower_bound(x); it != m.end(); )
{
    if (is_bad(it->second))
        m.erase(it++);
    else
        it++;
}
```

I can't use C++ though. I tried libavl, but it does not have lower_bound operation and also traversing breaks after deletion AFAIU.

Comment: Are you sure it's the best solution to whatever problem you have? Instead you might want to tell us about your *original* problem, and maybe we can help you solve that instead? Also see ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Maybe, some day, the Clang project will come up with an intermediate code generator that instantiates the C++ corresponding to the various template containers and algorithms for your concrete types. If that code is compilable under the C Standard, you would be done.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I need to store intervals ordered by left coordinate in a tree. When I add a new interval I have to check for intersections with existing intervals and then modify/remove intersecting intervals and insert new one or either do nothing. So intervals never intersect. Thus I look for last interval starting before newly inserted and then traverse to the right from it.

Comment: If I may interpret "I can't use C++" liberally, then you can write C++ modules that use `std::map` and give the public API C linkage with `extern "C"`.

Comment: Also, it sound like you need an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) rather than a vanilla BST.

Comment: @larsmans theoretically yes. But I'll have to redefine allocator (which may turn ugly) and mess with build system (which is undesired). Anyway it's an option.

Comment: @larsmans interval tree would be also fine, but not actually required (intervals are roughly of same small length)

Comment: @user2686820: why the custom allocator?

Comment: @larsmans non-standard memory management used here.. BTW it seems like I mislead everyone. I currently read about Threaded-Binary-Search-Trees.html on libavl docs and it looks like almost what i need.

Comment: @user2686820: threaded BSTs give constant-time "next" and "previous" operations on an iterator, but not necessarily stability in the face of deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding lower_bound to trb from libavl was easy. Uploaded it to github:

https://github.com/user15/trb-lb

P.S.: note, that it goes under GPL which may be unsuitable for proprietary code.